# Is there a maven plugin that verifies that all dependencies are releases?

Tags: maven-2, release

The 'maven-release-plugin' has this feature, but it is not available as separate goal.

I think I have seen this functionality somewhere, but I can't find it again. Would be great if somebody knows where to find such a plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [maven enforcer plugin](http:///maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-enforcer-plugin) has a [`requireReleaseDeps`](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/requireReleaseDeps.html) rule allowing to *enforce that no snapshots are included as dependencies*. It may be what you're looking for.

If you configure the plugin like this (check the rule documentation for more options):

```
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
   <plugins>
     <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-beta-1</version>
        <configuration>
          <rules>
            <requireReleaseDeps>
              <message>No Snapshots Allowed!</message>
            </requireReleaseDeps>
          </rules>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  [...]
</project>
```

Then calling `mvn enforcer:enforce` will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`release:prepare`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-release-plugin/prepare-mojo.html) together with `dryRun=true` should do what you want.